# Могут ли слова автора начинаться с многоточия?

Tags: пунктуация, диалог

Хотелось бы узнать, можно  ли начать слова автора с многоточия:

> — Перебор? — спросила девушка.
>
> К несчастью, сержант отметил, что нет, не перебор. Но отвечать не стал...
>
> — Ты не права, — **...и промолчать не мог.**

И корректно ли в таком случае не ставить многоточие после «...отвечать не стал»?

> К несчастью, сержант отметил, что нет, не перебор. Но отвечать не стал.
>
> — Ты не права, — ...и промолчать не мог.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы оформила **диалог так**:

*— Перебор? — спросила девушка.*

*К несчастью, отметил сержант, не перебор. Но отвечать  **не стал**.*

*— Ты не права. — **Промолчать совсем он не мог**.*

**Пояснение**

Обычно два многоточия ставятся при разрыве прямой речи, как у **[Розенталя, пункт 4](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=160#pp160).**

Разрыв **слов автора** мне не встречался. Как мне кажется, это выглядит не совсем обоснованно: ведь можно записать как-то иначе.